# Schedule command at specific time with Ansible

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

So I have been upgrading my server weekly for a while now by manually logging in and using

```
sudo at 2:30
```

This command prompts me for the commands I want to execute at 2:30 nighttime. The commands are:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade -y -qq
reboot
```

How can I move this to an Ansible playbook? I already reviewed their 'at'-module but it only lets me schedule commands relative to the current time (now + time) and not at a specific time. ([source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/at_module.html))

Another option would be to just create a raw task in the playbook, but how would I handle the fact that the `at` command is interactive?

P.S. The reason I want to manually go through this procedure and not delegate it to a cronjob is because I would like to review the packages which will be upgraded and their changelogs beforehand. It became my friday routine.

Comment: As far as I see you have conflicting requirements: "run via Ansible at some time" (i.e. automatically) and "I would like to review what packages to upgrade" (i.e. manually).

Comment: BTW, did you see https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades ?

Comment: I do not want the upgrades to run automatically. The Ansible playbook will be just for convenience, so I don't have to login to my server my self and type those commands. The apt report is sent to my e-mail every friday morning from which I review the changes and then proceed with the scheduling of the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that.

Here are couple of them:

1. Make a script with commands to execute.
   Upload it with `copy` module.
   Use `command` module to execute `at -f myscript 2:30`.
   This will add your commands to target hosts' queues.
2. Make Ansible playbook with `apt` module instead of your shell commands.
   Test it on a single server.
   Schedule it on your local machine (Ansible control host) with `at 2:30`,
   supply `ansible-playbook -i allservers upgrade-servers.yml` as job.
   This will execute your playbook on allservers at 2:30 from your local machine.
3. Modify [at](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/at.py) module to support `exact_time` parameter on par with `count`/`unit`.
   Save it as `./library/at.py` near your playbook.
   Apply it to schedule jobs at exact time on remote servers.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there was an easier solution. But I guess I just have to make the effort and modify the at module to support exact_time.

Comment: So here's the [modified at.py module](https://gist.github.com/boyd91/881f1cb2e5d1e66854242e4f7b6bcf0e) which supports all time expressions and not only 'now + '.